C source file change not showing up in program execution
Added a print statement to program source code (in C) in order to investigate a segmentation fault occurring on local machine during execution. Print statement does not show anything in execution, although it's placed within a scope which the program reaches (the valgrind stack trace indicated it was within one of the functions which ran before the segmentation fault). Program compiles without any issues. Seeking advice on how to resolve this so I can continue investigating the original issue.
Checked that bash was on the correct branch at compile time. The file change (the addition of the print statement) is acknowledged by my IDE (VSCode) which added the file marker M to the file. File change is noted in git status.

Use a debugger, not printf. (Probably a buffering issue but since you don't show any code...)

Maybe the segmentation fault already happened before it reaches your printf? Being in one of the functions doesn't mean being in the right place. If that function was in the call stack, was is also in a place before the next function in the call stack was called? Without showing any code, it is just wild guessing why you might do wrong. Using a debugger as suggested would clearly help.

The stdout buffer used by printf is probably not being flushed before the program crashes. Use fflush(stdout) after the print.

I've tried this as well but it hasn't made a difference

Or print to stderr which is unbuffered.
